# I'm using rtMedia and Youzer. Can Shortcodes be used to display a video gallery?

Tags: shortcode

Please be patient if This doesn't make sense.

I'm using Youzer which adds advanced social networking features to BuddyPress. I also added rtmedia to allow users to upload videos. How do I use the shortcodes to show a video album of whatever users page I click on?

Example - Bob visits the site to look up Bill, once he is on bills profile I would like the videos that Bill uploaded to appear under a new tab.

Could I create my own string to get the user id or do I have to manually add the album to each new member?[image]

That image is the tab I want to tell Wordpress to display the users' videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with BuddyPress and a total stranger to rtmedia. But out of curiosity I had a brief look at their documentations. Perhaps you could add a [custom shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to your `functions.php`, which gets the current profile ID and uses it with the rtmedia gallery shortcode to display videos from the profile.

Something along these lines,

```
function my_profile_videos_shortocde( $atts ) {
  $profile_id = bp_displayed_user_id(); // not sure if this is the right function
  if ( ! $profile_id ) {
    return;
  }
  return do_shortode( '[rtmedia_gallery media_type="video" media_author="' . $profile_id . '"]' ); // add parameters to the shortcode as needed
}
add_shortcode( 'profile_videos', 'my_profile_videos_shortocde' );
```

You should then be able to use `[profile_videos]` on the Tab content field.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to learn to code as I go along because doing helps better than watching or reading. The way I took it was to just add the shortcode. I didn't know you can build your own. I appreciate the help.